# Is it possible to add ASCII art to a javascript popup?

Tags: javascript, php, ascii-art

I am having issues creating a simple way to dynamically add ascii art to an actual javascript confirmation popup. 
I'm sure many of you are like.. WHY>!>@! and to that.. I say.. because ;)

Now I might be able to make a line or 2 work, but each time I write some ascii art, its pretty unique.. so.. can anyone think of a function that might make it easier?

Here is an example of the closest I've gotten. (which isn't very far at all)

```
<? 
$rusure = "\n"; 
$rusure =. "   __           __                  ___  \n";
$rusure =. "  /__\  /\ /\  / _\_   _ _ __ ___  / _ \ \n";
$rusure =. " / \// / / \ \ \ \| | | | '__/ _ \ \// / \n";
$rusure =. "/ _  \ \ \_/ / _\ \ |_| | | |  __/   \/  \n";
$rusure =. "\/ \_/  \___/  \__/\__,_|_|  \___|   ()  \n";
$rusure =. "                                         \n";
?>

<button type="button" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this?\nIt will be GONE FOREVER.. and there is no undo..<?=$rusure?>')){ document.location.href='' }">DELETE FOREVER</button>
```

Comment: `confirm` and its friends are obnoxious and ugly at the best of times. Why not do this with HTML and make a `<div>` appear when needed? You can make those look like anything you want.

Answer (score 5):

It'll probably be a lot easier if you write the code in a Javascript template literal instead, that way you don't have to worry about all the concatenation and newlines, you can simply create the art string. Use `String.raw` to ensure the backslashes are interpreted as literal backslashes rather than escape characters:

```js
const artStr = String.raw`
   __           __                  ___ xx
  /__\  /\ /\  / _\_   _ _ __ ___  / _ \yy
 / \// / / \ \ \ \| | | | '__/ _ \ \// /xx
/ _  \ \ \_/ / _\ \ |_| | | |  __/   \/ yy
\/ \_/  \___/  \__/\__,_|_|  \___|   () xx
                                        
`;
alert(artStr);
```

That said, the actual effect won't be reliable, because the font of the `alert` box is up to the browser (and the browser only) - it can't be changed via Javascript. If the user's browser happens to use a monospaced font, it may work, but otherwise, it'll just look like a mess.

Consider using something more user-friendly and customizable than `alert`, such as an actual element on the page (whose font you can adjust, and which won't *block*).

```js
const artStr = String.raw`
   __           __                  ___ xx
  /__\  /\ /\  / _\_   _ _ __ ___  / _ \yy
 / \// / / \ \ \ \| | | | '__/ _ \ \// /xx
/ _  \ \ \_/ / _\ \ |_| | | |  __/   \/ yy
\/ \_/  \___/  \__/\__,_|_|  \___|   () xx
                                        
`;
const makeCustomAlert = str => {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = 'customAlert';
  str = str
    .replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;')
    .replace(/\\/g, '&bsol;')
  container.innerHTML = str;
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  container.onclick = () => container.remove();
};
makeCustomAlert(artStr);
```

```css
.customAlert {
  font-family: "consolas";
  background-color: yellow;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: for anyone seeing this: this answer works perfectly if using <pre> tag instead of div and using monospace font (or any font with identical width, I think)